# How to extract the part of code into framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a project. And part of it is very general and can be developed separately. So I want to extract it into some framework/library. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: When creating a new project in Xcode, one of the types you can make is a Static Library.  Make one of those, and then you can link your other projects to it.  There are plenty of SO questions about how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same situation to do so. You have to create library first and then convert it to framework.

Here is a very helpful link that you can follow (it is the same for framework for both objective c and swift).

http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

Be very careful for .m and .h files. Sometimes, you have same declaration of the class and different implementation. In this case you can include .h files only. If you forget some .m files you will get linker-o error for missing symbol, and if you forget to remove from build phases some you will get duplicate symbol.

Hope this helps, if I remember something more I edit this answer.